# Dynamically Changing X-axis and Y-axis Titles Using layout.updatemenus[] Dropdown

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, plotly, axis-labels

I have Python Dash App which displays a `Plotly graph_object.scatter plot` with multiple traces that I can switch between using a `layout.updatemenus[]` dropdown menu.

The problem that I'm facing is that depending on which dropdown menu option is selected, the `x-axis` and `y-axis` should have different titles.

As of now, neither axis has any title, but I can add a permanent title (that is, one that does not change dynamically based on which trace is showing) by using the `xaxis_title` and `yaxis_title` attributes of the `figure.update_layout` method. I cannot, however, pass a `list` or a dictionary for `xaxis_title` or `yaxis_title` (it only accepts a string or an int).

I'm currently envisioning a series of if/else statements that finds which dropdown menu option currently has 'ShowActive' set to True and changes the xaxis_title and yaxis_title attributes based on that. But I don't know how to write it so that this axis-title-changing function will run whenever a new menu option is selected.

I can update this question with code samples if necessary.

Comment: On a side note, I understand there is a way to do this if I use dcc.dropdown and set up a callback instead of using layout.updatemenus[], but due to the way I have the app currently set up, it would take a lot of work and affect a lot of other elements of the app to make that change, so I want to try to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Please add a [mcve](/help/mcve). Can this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62937509/plotly-custom-buttons-is-it-possible-to-set-the-same-scale-for-multiple-subplot/62946616#62946616) help?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the x-axis labels and y-axis labels on update as follows:

```
updatemenus = list([
dict(active=-1,
     buttons=list([   
        dict(label = 'High',
             method = 'update',
             args = [{'visible': [True, True, False, False]},
                     {'title': 'Yahoo High',
                      'xaxis': {'title': 'Date'},
                      'yaxis': {'title': 'High Price - Dollars'},
                      'annotations': high_annotations}]),
        dict(label = 'Low',
             method = 'update',
             args = [{'visible': [False, False, True, True]},
                     {'title': 'Yahoo Low',
                      'xaxis': {'title': 'Date'},
                      'yaxis': {'title': 'Low Price - Dollars'},
                      'annotations': low_annotations}]),
```

In `args`, you can change the `'xaxis' : {'title' : 'CHANGE X-AXIS LABEL'}` to achieve this.

*Answer sourced from: https://community.plotly.com/t/changing-the-xy-axis-titles-with-dropdown-menu/5421/2.*